# Slash issues in sites which use React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Already week I stumbled a bug which related `React-router`.Firstly I think this bug is only in my site.Then I find out that a giant corporation's that use a **ReactJS** have same issue.

If you wrote more than one slash in url and press enter you will see the (small)site(s) show `header` and `footer`.

And giant project's behaviour will be unusual.Some of components will be break some of them will not shown.

Example of this project's.

[**Marvel**](https://www.marvel.com//), [**Airbnb**](https://www.airbnb.ru//)

So.I try to clean up my URL.

```
if (window.location.pathname.length > 1) {
      // const url = window.location.pathname.slice(0, 1);
      const url = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/\//g, "");
      history.push(`${url}`);
}
```

I don't know why  this try not work.

[**Codesandbox**](https://nn8x24vm60.csb.app/) for test.If you write more than one slash in url it will show only list of component's.How to fix that?

Comment: would you care to share source code of your route

Comment: @techipank take any route as you want and fix this issue please.I gave a Codesandbox url in question.

Comment: Hi, would love to dig into that, can you provide the CODE behind the CodeSandBox example you provided?

Comment: @SultanH. here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-ympgg this show only one component whatever the url changes

Comment: @techipank I added my codesandbox please see in comment above

Comment: I have seen it, but the porblem is with `Route` components that you have, it should be fixable there, or, didn't you implement such routing system?

Comment: @SultanH. I don't understand.Where need to implement routing system? Should you provide  a demo in codesandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this, as a replacement to your `Main`.

- It will fix the double or more slashes issure.
- It fixed the static render for every route as only only component.

Full [CodeSaneBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-1k5y5?fontsize=14).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Roster from "./Roster";
import Schedule from "./Schedule";

// The Main component renders one of the three provided
// Routes (provided that one matches). Both the /roster
// and /schedule routes will match any pathname that starts
// with /roster or /schedule. The / route will only match
// when the pathname is exactly the string "/"

class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fixDoubleSlash();
  }

  // Will check for double slashes and redirect to the correct path.
  fixDoubleSlash = () => {
    const {
      location: { pathname },
      history: { push }
    } = this.props;

    if (pathname.match(/\/{2,}/g)) {
      push(pathname.replace(/\/{2,}/g, "/"));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/roster" component={Roster} />
        <Route path="/schedule" component={Schedule} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.But there error throw in codesandbox =( . `Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'`.

Comment: You're welcome, Its working perfectly on [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-jyi4q)

Comment: Component's not mounting.

Comment: Fixed the case of more than two slashes, but, you actually shouldn't go that deep on it, I updated the answer and the code in the sandbox.

Comment: Okay =( ty anyway.

Comment: Oh, Sorry if this was impolite or something, is it fixed as you wish?

Comment: It's remove the slashes that's the good part.Unfortunately  component's not mounting properly that's the problem which need to be fixed.Every route show only one component `Welcome to the Tornadoes Website!`

Comment: What will happen if user tries to request `url /home/notExist` or any other url this works for only `/`

Comment: It will actually work for all cases with double or more repeated slashes @techipank

Comment: @Spectr I have an update that covers more cases, now the problem is the rendering of the components was broken even with the sandbox you provided, if you want to dig in that I can give it a try

Comment: @SultanH. yes it will work for double or n number of slashes but my question was what if user given some text in url for which in application is not having any route it will fail i guess

Comment: @SultanH. If you give a try to solve it  that  will be great.

Comment: @techipank sorry man but your code will show `NotFound` component in every page which I don't want.

Comment: @Spectr I have fixed it, it's in the `Main` component, also I have moved the logic of `fixDoubleSlashes` to the _Main_ component instead of the _App_.

Comment: The problem is that you needed `exact` in the route `to='/'`, which, if it doesn't exist, will deal with all routes as they are part of `/`..

Answer (score 1):

use window.history.pushstate

```
if (window.location.pathname.length > 1) {
      // const url = window.location.pathname.slice(0, 1);
      const url = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/\//g, "");
      window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', url); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define one component as `NotFound` which will render in case user tries to access any path which doesn't exist in the application.

in your Route add this

```
<Route component={NotFound} />
```

and this should be present at the end of all route otherwise you request for any URL it will go to NotFound.

Comment: please see this link https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/react-tips-handling-404-pages-24d27191a8dd i checked your code you added at wrong place

Comment: If you found your answer please accept the answer and close this ticket